# How to refer EA Element using EA Attribute property Type

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to refer to an EA Element using EA Attribute property 'Type' through Add-in by using the below code

```
RefAttEle.Type = "{3020EA93-AA94-49aa-850F-EDFF39F2E9DD}";
```

By using the above code EA Attribute property 'Type' value is not referring to EA Element instead of that EA Attribute property 'Type' value is begin sets as 'String'. Please refer the below image.

[image]

How to refer to EA Element using EA Attribute property 'Type' (Add-In) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set

```
RefAttEle.ClassifierID = <theElement>.ElementId
```